# How to supply default values for python functions which accept integer

Tags: python

I have a very simple Python function which is like this :

```
def test(var=None):
    if not var:
        raise ValueError("Something is wrong")
    else:
        var = var + 10
    return var


values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
check = list(map(test, values))
print(check)
```

So basically var variable in Python accepts an integer value and i have to supply a default argument .

I get the below error message when i run this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "First.py", line 10, in <module>
    check = list(map(test, values))
  File "First.py", line 3, in test
    raise ValueError("Something is wrong")
ValueError: Something is wrong
```

I think this is because of the 0 i am passing at the end.

Can someone tell me a solution to this issue . How do i supply a default value to the function and also pass 0 to it at the same time.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it's the zero at the end. Compare explicitly to `None`: `if var is None`...

Answer (score 2):

In your case, just make this `var` positional, not optional:

```
def test(var):
    return var + 10
```

In the general case, compare against `None` using `is`, like this:

```
def test(var=None):
    if var is None:
        # handle this
```